# How to specify number of threads for distributed executor service Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to play with the distributed executor service in hazelcast.

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
IExecutorService es = hz.getExecutorService("default1");
```

I know that `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(8)` is the way to set the number of threads for normal executor service, but not sure about the Distributed ExecutorService

```
ExecutorConfig ecfg = new ExecutorConfig();
ecfg.setPoolSize(5);
config.addExecutorConfig(ecfg);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

You can also make use of the xml configuration. You can find examples here:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-book-examples

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-book-examples/tree/master/chapter-distributed-executor/scale-up

Comment: Link has changed to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-executor/scale-up